# correct setting prerender-spa-plugin

Tags: vue.js, prerender

I am trying to configure a `prerender-spa-plugin` for my application.
Need to configure for multiple pages.

I do, as in [documentation](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) (Vue.js 2 Router)

I added the necessary parameters to file webpack.prod.config.js

```
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin')
const Renderer = PrerenderSPAPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {

...

  plugins: [

        // == PRERENDER SPA PLUGIN == //
        new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
            staticDir: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
            routes: ['/', '/test'],

            renderer: new Renderer({
                inject: {
                    foo: 'bar'
                },
                headless: false,
                renderAfterDocumentEvent: 'render-event'
            })
        }),
...
```

Also in the file `main.js`

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
    render: h => h(App),
    mounted () {
        // You'll need this for renderAfterDocumentEvent.
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('render-event'))
    }
})
```

Now about the main problem.
At the root(`/`) of the project, pre-rendering is working.
If you go to the page `/test`, then in the source code `(ctrl + u)` will show the code from the site root(`/`).

I can't find content from `/test` in any way.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix the problem.

Thank!

UPD:routes.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import test from '@/components/test'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'HelloWorld',
            component: HelloWorld
        },
        {
            path: '/test',
            name: 'test',
            component: test
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: In order to verify that prerender does not work as expected, please, check html output inside `dist` folder. There should be `test` folder with `index.html`. If it has valid content for that page, then it is possible that production server is not configured correctly.

Comment: @aBiscuit Inside this file is the code from the main page.

Comment: `prerender-spa-plugin` is pretty straightforward. Please, try removing additional configuration from `new Renderer` options and check if you have same results in generated files. Also, please, add router configuration to the question.

Comment: @aBiscuit I removed the parameter, nothing has changed.

Added route